# Python Syntax Error while inserting string variable

Tags: python

Simple error while inserting variable . Can't seem to figure it out ! `meaning` and `word` are of type str .

```
rest_command = "display notification \'%s\' with title \'%s\'", %(meaning[0],word[0])
os.system(osascript -e + rest_command)
```

Error:

```
File "word-scraper.py", line 20
    rest_command = "display notification \'%s\' with title \'%s\'", %(meaning[0],word[0])
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's the comma in aid of?

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the comma

```
>>> "display notification \'%s\' with title \'%s\'" % (meaning[0],word[0])
"display notification 'hello' with title 'foo'"
```

Or use `format`

```
>>> "display notification \'{}\' with title \'{}\'".format(meaning[0],word[0])
"display notification 'hello' with title 'foo'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the comma between the string and the '%'.